# Using profile in Watir and Webdriver

Tags: google-chrome, webdriver, watir, profile, watir-webdriver

My question is regarding modify default profile settings to allow/deny access of mic and cam by my web app. Here is the code - which seems to be ignored.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'watir-webdriver'

profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Profile.new
profile['content_settings.pattern_pairs.*,*.media-stream-mic'] = 1 
# if I put mysever.com into here (first asterix), the parsing must fail 
# as the '.' is used as delimiter by profile.rb - so *,* should work 

browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :profile => profile 
browser.goto "http://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/input/index.html" 
# here a get media event is fired and the browser should proceed without(!)
# asking the user for permission - but the browser is always asking and 
# this element is not accessible for Watir (is it?).
```

I had a look into profile.rb where just the parsing takes place - which is also somehow problematic (see comment inline).

I also searched the web but could not find anything.

Holger

Comment: I recognize its now 5 years later, but did you by any chance come up with a solution to this

Answer (score 0):

```
1. create a profile manually using the cmd :
 firefox -profilemanager
 set what you want on the browser of the new profile 
2.code example 

protected void initializeWebDriver() {  
        LoggerInfo.logger.info("Starting webdriver...");
        ProfilesIni allProfiles = new ProfilesIni();
        FirefoxProfile profile = allProfiles.getProfile("MyProfile");
//      FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
        driver = new    DriverBuilder().using(Browser.FIREFOX).withFirefoxProfile(profile).build();
        LoggerInfo.logger.info("webdriver is up");
    }
```